Clarification required: No non empty metric space is open in every possible superspace
I am reading Michael Searcoid-"Metric Spaces", where, in page 64, example 4.6.1, the following is shown:
Theorem: There exists no non-empty metric space which is open relative to every possible superspace.
Proof: Let $X$ be a non empty metric space and suppose $X \cap \mathbb{R}^+= \varnothing.^{1} $ Let $p \in X$ be fixed. Define $Y=X \cup \mathbb{R}^+$. Extend $d:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}^+ $ to $Y \times Y$ by setting $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ if $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb{R}^+$. If $x \in X$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}$, let $$d(x,y)=d(y,x)=d(x,p)+y \tag{(*)}$$ This forms a metric on $Y$. Moreover, $\operatorname{dist}_Y(p,\mathbb{R}^+)=0$. Therefore, we note that $\operatorname{dist}_Y(q,X^C) \not > 0 $ for some $q \in X$, which makes it non-open. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
 1: If this is not the case, the argument can be modified using, instead of $\mathbb{R}^+$, some order isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{R}^+$ that has empty intersection with $X$. It can be shown within set theory that there is such a copy.

The problem I have with this proof is the use of $\mathbb{R}^+$ and the footnote (1). What if my space is itself $\mathbb{R^+}$? The footnote states we can find an order isomorphic copy of $\mathbb{R}^+$ that is disjoint from $\mathbb{R}^+$. Won't issue arise when we speak about that $\mathbb{R}^+$ in the metric itself? On defining the new metric, we exploit the fact that our "extension" space is $\mathbb{R^+} $ and that we can define the metric in the equation (*) by directly referring to the $\mathbb{R^+}$ we have chosen. Let us call $E$ that set that is order isomorphic to $\mathbb{R^+}$. Is it, then, that the $\mathbb{R^+}$ we talk about in the metric $d$, is this set $E$? I feel like some explanation is required here.

If you have a bijection $j: E \to \mathbb{R}^+$ then you can define a metric on $E$:
$$d_E : (x,y) \in E^2 \mapsto |j(x) - j(y)|$$
which will essentially make $E$ into a metric-space-copy of $\mathbb{R}^+$, and I assume that's the implied construction here, especially since you can then replace the lone $y$ in $(*)$ by $j(y)$ to have a well-defined expression.
